# Count the number of open browser tabs in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: python, firefox

I want to make a function that counts the number of open tabs in the browser - Chrome or Firefox - using Java or Python. I know Firefox and Chrome tab counters exist, because there are *AddOns* and *Extensions* that achieve that, but I cannot export the value to another function like I want.

Does anyone know the API call?

Answer (score 1):

Unless Firefox exposes an API for other programs (not addons nor extensions) to control and query its internal state (a quick Google search suggests that it doesn't), I suspect you'll be out of luck.